# Прошу совета js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно вызывать смену координат карты при определенном условии...

есть код

```
if (typeof map135 != 'undefined') {
  map135.setView([json.lat, json.lng], 17);
}
```

Все отлично работает, но это id карты меняется и тут проблема...

чтобы вывести map135, где 135 это как раз динамика я его записываю

```
var $geo_id= $('option:selected', this).attr('data-geo-id'),
```

И вывожу пытаюсь вывести

```
if (typeof map$geo_id != 'undefined') {
   map$geo_id.setView([json.lat, json.lng], 17);
}
```

Но такая конструкция не работает и в консоле пусто...

Comment: что такое `map135`? как ты объявляешь эту переменную?

Comment: Это карта 2GIS (Leaflet), map135 это карта с id 135

Comment: где именно ты ее объявляешь?

Comment: смотрите даже            var $map = 'dfgdfgdf';
     
   if (typeof $map != 'undefined') {
       $map.setView([json.lat, json.lng], 17);
   }  Ошибка  Uncaught TypeError: $map.setView is not a function

Comment: не подставляет значения переменной var...

Comment: оно и не должно поставляться. По приведенному куску кода, вообще непонятно что ты хочешь делать и почему у строки пытаешься вызвать метод, которого у нее точно нет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101246/discussion-between-grundy-and--).

Comment: Я через ajax получаю geo_id (грубо говоря id карты коих много), дале записываю в var и хочу подставить в название  map$geo_id.setView([json.lat, json.lng], 17);, так как map135.setView([json.lat, json.lng], 17); работает (Меняет позиционирования координат)

Comment: Попробуйте `window['map'+$geo_id]`. А так жесть, конечно)

Comment: Да так работает, а почему жесть ?